# 2 dropdowns, connected with each other, ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, dropdown

I am struggling with one idea and I need help.

I have a dropdown and dropup list and they contain the same 2 images(flags). In dropup list I select 1 flag and I want in other list to automaticlly be selected the remaining flag.

For now I have hard coded images but eventually I want to display them dynamically.

```
return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className={isClicked ? "div2" : "div1"}>
          <div class="dropup">
            <button class="dropbtn">Dropup</button>
            <div class="dropup-content">
              <a href="#">
                <img src={logoEn} alt="logo" />
              </a>
              <a href="#">
                <img src={logoDe} alt="logo" />
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <input />
        </div>
        <div id="switch">
          <button onClick={this.toggleBox}>
            <img src={iconSwitch} alt="logo" />
          </button>{" "}
        </div>
        <div className={isClicked ? "div1" : "div2"}>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">
                <img src={logoEn} alt="logo" />
              </a>
              <a href="#">
                <img src={logoDe} alt="logo" />
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <input />
        </div>
      </div>
```

I want this to be solved in ReactJS, if anybody have some idea how to solve please let me know.

Br

C

Comment: Please post the code you have attempted, and the specific issue you have. No one will write it all for you. As a starting point, I suggest you read into react component states

Comment: Of course Kieran that was not my plan for others to solve everything, but just to give me a little push since I have no idea how to evan start and I have worked with state before.